# SpriteKit interplay between line and node: line should give a direction and speed to the node

Tags: path, sprite-kit, line, nodes, direction

I would like to have the following interplay between line and ball in my game: a line gives direction and speed to the ball. The longer the line, the faster the ball.

What I have now: a ball is following the line and stops at the end of it. But it shouldn't stop here. Of course, I understand that the ball is only following the path I made. But how could I change it?

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

// Basic for dynamic sizes step01
var width = CGFloat()
var height = CGFloat()

var ball:SKSpriteNode!

var line:SKShapeNode!
var startPoint: CGPoint!
var location = CGPoint()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = .purple

    //declare dynamic size of the screen
    width = self.frame.size.width
    height = self.frame.size.height

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero

    createBall()

}

func createBall(){
    ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yellowBtn")
    ball.position = CGPoint(x:0, y: -(height/2.5))
    ball.size     = CGSize(width: width/6, height: width/6)

    self.addChild(ball)
}

func drawLine(endPoint:CGPoint){

    if(line != nil ){ line.removeFromParent() }

    startPoint = ball.position

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: startPoint)
    path.addLine(to: endPoint)

    line = SKShapeNode()
    line.path = path
    line.lineWidth = 5
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.white

    self.addChild(line)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if(line != nil ){ line.removeFromParent()

    for touch in (touches ) {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        drawLine(endPoint: location)
    }
  }
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ) {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
            drawLine(endPoint: location)

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in (touches ) {
          location = touch.location(in: self)
          drawLine(endPoint: location)
    }

    let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: location, duration: 10)
    ball.run(moveAction)
}



override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

}
```

}

[image: start point]
[image: end point I have now]

Answer (score 0):

I have found at least a part of answer to my question: I need to calculate CGVector manually (lastPoint - firstPoint) and then apply impulse to the ball:

```
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in (touches ) {
          location = touch.location(in: self)
          drawLine(endPoint: location)
    }

    let dx = location.x - startPoint.x
    let dy = location.y - startPoint.y

    let movement = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(movement)


}
```

Now I should find the second part: how to set the speed of the ball accordingly to the length of the line.

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing when you use the vector?   Longer line means longer vector, which is a higher impulse thus faster speed.